# Can click decorators work nicely on non-main functions?

Tags: python, python-click

I would like to have some CLI options to be re-used between two programs that share a common library file.  Currently, each file has a similar structure to the following:

```py
from .shared import G

@click.command()
@click.option("--thing1", …)
@click.optoin("--thing2", …)
…
def main(**kwargs):
    g = G()
    g.do_your_thing()
```

What I'd like to do is move all that to the `__init__` of `G` or a subclass of `G`.

```py
class G:
    @click.command()
    @click.option("--thing1")
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        pass

class G6(G):
    @click.command()
    @click.option("--specific-flag")
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if kwargs.get("--specific-flag"):
             do_something()
        self.seven = 7
```

However, when I try this, I get the following error.

```
Usage: something.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'something.py --help' for help.

Error: no such option: --thing1
```

---

My primary goal with this refactoring is to eliminate lots of duplicative code decorating the `main` function of each program by moving the shared decorators to the library.

If this is possible, is it also possible to use an option decorator of the subclass to supersede the same decorator on the base class?  I assume the answer is yes.

---

## Edit

Based on the answer below, my program now works with a structure similar to the following snippet:

```py
_common_options = [
    click.option(…), click.option(…), …
]

def common_options(func):
    for option in _common_options:
        func = option(func)
    return func

class G:
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        print(kwargs)

@click.command()
@common_options
@click.option("--specific-option", …)
def main(**kwargs):
    f = G(**kwargs)
```

The problem with my original attempt was putting all the `@click.whatever` stuff as a decorator of `__init__` instead of decorating `main` and passing `**kwargs` to `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done previously was create a list of options to be applied to a command or group. For example:

```py
_global_options = [
    click.option('-v', '--verbose', count=True, default=0, help='Verbose output.'),
    click.option('-n', '--dry-run', is_flag=True, default=False, help='Dry-run mode.')
]


def common_options(func):
    for option in reversed(_global_options):
        func = option(func)
    return func
```

These would then be applied as such:

```py
click.group(name='my_group')
@common_options
def my_group(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Decorators seem to work really well with Click.
Does this help?

Comment: It’s moved the point where I’m getting the error from Click complaining about an unexpected option to a Type Error of click’s Context object receiving an unexpected keyword argument in its `__init__`. I’m struggling to figure out how to architect my program from the official click documentation because their examples are too minimal for me to get a good feel on how the pieces are supposed to fit together.

Comment: Has your code changed since you posted the original one? If yes, could you please update it so I can better see what's now the issue?

Comment: I was getting the error because I had forgotten to move everything into `_common_options`.  I've updated my question to reflect things working with your answer.